# Can my spouse travel to UK alone on a visitor visa and then join me?

Tags: visas, uk

I've been granted a Business Visa to UK. In my visa application and in my cover letter I mentioned that my wife will travel along with me and I will be paying for her entire UK trip.

My wife too mentioned, in her cover letter and visa application, that she will travel with me to UK and my husband (myself) paying for her entire trip to UK.

Unfortunately, my wife's visitor visa was denied because of some small mistakes and I was granted Business Visa.

My wife is applying once again for visitor visa with more documentation and explanation.

The problem is I have to travel in few days and I really cannot wait for my wife to get her visitor visa so that she too could travel along with me.

Want to know if I can travel alone to UK and then can my wife join me later in UK once she get's her standard visa?

Will the Immigration Officer at the Heathrow airport allow her to enter UK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Want to know if I can travel alone to UK and then can my wife join me later in UK once she get's her standard visa?**

That's fine. This is not an unusual case.  Your wife should explain this in her application.

**Will the Immigration Officer at the Heathrow airport allow her to enter UK?**

If she has an entry clearance in her passport with all the implicit caveats (not forged etc), then the IO will land her in the normal case.  You should absolutely be in the arrivals gallery with a name tag or something else that makes you easy to identify in case the IO wants to ask you a question.  It's all very normal.